What encryption method is used by the compression utility in Debian 11 Cinnamon
I just use the preinstalled utility with ''right click > compression'' and it gives me the option to make a 7z file and also to protect it with a password. Does this procedure produces an encrypted file with AES-256 method which is the one used the 7 zip application for Windows?


There's no such thing as a 'compression utility' in Debian, its derivatives, or any other distro. There's a frontend and/or a file manager plugin/feature that relies on several installed programs to handle different types of compressed files. Results are indistinguishable from using those tools directly.

Thanks for the answer

Yes.
The main features of the 7z format:
...
Strong AES-256 encryption
...


Source


Yes I know that, my question is if those features of 7z are implemented in the utility of Nemo file manager of Cinnamon... The one I use

Again, Nemo does nothing in this regard on its own. It merely calls the installed tools to do the job. You're confusing a frontend with the actual tool.

Thanks for clarifying. So that application in the screenshot does encrypt with AES-256?

Yes, you can also confirm this by executing 7z l -slt <archive_name>.7z. This will show you metadata about the archive. The line "Method = LZMA2:12 7zAES" confirms that it uses "7zAES" which is AES-256; According to one of the 7z devs https://sourceforge.net/p/p7zip/patches/25/#3da5

Thanks for clarifying
